# Is my proof about even almost perfect numbers valid?

Tags: number-theory

I think that I've discovered a proof that if an even almost perfect number is not of the form $2^k$ it has to have at least 3 distinct primes.

Let $2^k.y^m $ be an even almost perfect number where $y^m$ is odd.

$σ(2^k.y^m) = (2^{k+1}-1)(y^m+y^{m-1} ... + y + 1) = 2^{k+1} . y^m - 1 $

$2^{k+1} . y^m + 2^{k+1}(y^{m-1}+y^{m-2} ... + y + 1) - 1(y^m+y^{m-1} ... + y) - 1 = 2^{k+1}.y^m-1$.

$2^{k+1}(y^{m-1}+y^{m-2} ... + y + 1) - 1(y^m+y^{m-1} ... + y) = 0$

$2^{k+1}(y^{m-1}+y^{m-2} ... + y + 1) = y(y^{m-1} + y^{m-2} ... + 1)$

$2^{k+1} = y$ which is a contradiction because y is an odd prime.

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof, which looks fine to me, implies that an even almost perfect number cannot have two prime factors. This implies an even almost perfect number can either have one prime factor (in which case it is only $2$), or it must have more than two prime factors.

It is a known fact about even almost perfect numbers that "[the only known almost perfect numbers are powers of $2$ with non-negative exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number)". Your proof is in agreement with this statement.